# Images pixelated in higher resolutions

Tags: libgdx, screen-resolution

I'm developing a game using libGDX framework but I have some problems trying to adapt it to different resolutions. I'll give an example of the problems I'm having.

I use Scene2D to show a simple menu. That menu have some buttons with textures loaded from a texture atlas (button textures are 9patch). In desktop, with a resolution of 800x480 the buttons look nice (even the BitmapFont) but in Android, where I use setViewport to keep the width (800px) but scale the height keeping the aspect ratio, I get pixelated images. I think that this is because my mobile higher resolution. The whole stage must be scaled to fit so the images appear pixelated.

So, my question is, what is the best way to solve this? How can I support different resolutions without end with a pixel art look?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html read this before

Answer (score 0):

What resolution is the android device you tested it on? You said you've used 9-patch images. This should not produce pix-elated results unless your setting them to a size and then modifying their scale(difference between screen resolution and viewport size). If you don't want any scaling you should use your screens width or height for the viewport and calculate the other one by keeping your aspect ratio. This means that you'll have to build all your object's sizes at runtime based on your new viewport.

There isn't a one way fit all solution for such problems so you'll have to find which one suits your app. You can define your button sizes as % of screen's width or height; Or set them to a fixed value and adjust the spaces between them; or a combination of both(make an object partially bigger and modify the space between them).